# What is the meaning of this notation? $Z: (0,1)$

Tags: probability, actuarial-science

I understand that it is a mapping onto all real numbers and the piecewise part but not the $Z: (0,1)$ part. [Image of Problem Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWD4r.png)

Comment: It's the usual notation: $f\colon A\to B$ is a function from $A$ to $B$. In this case, the domain is $(0,1)=\{x\,|\, 0<x<1\}$.

Comment: $Z$ on the open interval domain of $s=(0,1)$

Comment: You forgot the extra "arrow then R" in your title notation.

Comment: @coffeemath That's not forgetting, it is a symptom of the confusion, I think.

Answer (score 1):

It means that $Z$ is a function with domain $(0,1)$, i.e. the interval of all real numbers between $0$ and $1$, excluding the end points $0$ and $1$, and the co-domain is the real numbers. So $Z$ maps some number $0<x<1$ into a real number $Z(x).$

Answer (score 1):

You didn't put the whole line into the question.  The line confusing you is
$$
Z:(0,1) \to \Bbb{R}$$
and the meaning of that statement is

- $Z:$} "$Z$ is a map"
- $(0,1)$ "from the open interval $0$ to $1$"
- **$\to \Bbb{R}$ "to the reals."**